# At least an orthogonal projection inside a side

Tags: geometry

Let $P$ a point inside a convex n-agon and let $P_1, P_2, ..., P_n$ the ortogonal projections of $P$ on the sides of the n-agon. How can I show that at least one of these projections lies inside a side of the poligon? I tried to prove that a convex n-agon is dibisible in $n$ triangle with $P$ and two vertex of the n-agone as vertex with all the angles $\leq 90°$ but I failed... any advice/solution? Thanks :)

Comment: One easy way is work with a triangle, and for general polygon $P_1P_2\dots P_n$, divide it into $n-1$ triangles.

Comment: How do you divide the polygon? I didn't understand your construction

Comment: Ah, never mind, it seems I was trying to solve another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that's not the case, and each orthogonal projection is outside the polygon.

Let $A$ be the closest polygon vertex to $P$, and let $B$ be a neighboring vertex. Let's find the locus points such that $P_1 = \text{proj}_{AB}(P) \notin AB$.

There are two possibilities.

1. $\angle PAB > \frac{\pi}{2}$. Construct a line $g$ perpendicular to $PA$ through $A$. Then $B$ must be in the half-plane bordered by $g$ not containing $X$.
2. $\angle PBA > \frac{\pi}{2}$. In this case B is inside the circle with diameter PA. However, since $A$ was chosen to be the vertex closest to $P$, this is impossible.

Finally, $A$ has two neighbors. However, having both of then in the half-plane described below line $g$ violates convexity, a contradiction.

[image]

Comment: In your demonstration I see more or less a red line, but, pardon me, there is a lot of imprecision : I don't understand why angle PAB $> \pi/2$ and angle PBA $> \pi/2$ are exclusive one from the other, and why $C$ would be necessarily on the exterior side of g because it an not belong to the interior  of the circle, etc...

Comment: @JeanMarie Angle PAB and PBA can't both be obtuse, as triangle PAB can't have two obtuse angles. For the rest, the same logic that applies to B applies to C just as well. I'd be happy to clarify parts of the argument, but I'm not sure what is unclear.

Comment: But why couldn't they _both_ be acute ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Then the orthogonal projection of X on AB would be on the side AB, contradiction the assumption.

Comment: I begin to understand. Thanks !